# Run code or set environment variable before meson cross-compile setup is run

Tags: emscripten, meson-build

I'm cross compiling to WASM using emscripten using meson and the cross file I have currently looks like this:

```
[binaries]
c = 'emcc'
cpp = 'em++'
ar = 'emar'
ranlib = 'emranlib'
pkgconfig = 'pkg-config'
strip = 'strip'

[project options]
sharedlib = false

[host_machine]
cpu = 'wasm'
cpu_family = 'wasm'
endian = 'little'
system = 'emscripten'

[properties]
sys_root = '$EM_CACHE/sysroot'
```

What bothers me is that last line - I'm setting the EM_CACHE variable manually but it can be derived with `em-config CACHE`. I'm not sure what order meson runs the build configuration but it seems that when you specify --cross-file it pre-empts anything in meson.build, so I'm unable to pre-set that variable.

Is there a way to set this, or set a variable that can be used in the cross file, or is there just a better/more graceful way to do this that I've missed?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @Martin I'm afraid I've yet to find a more elegant solution.